# Why this issue could lead to a CSRF problem?

Tags: security

I'm a web developer with some knowledge about security and I'm discussing with a professional security expert about if one case it's or isn't vulnerable to a CSRF attack. Let me explain it:

I have a typical change password form, where I ask the old password, and the new one twice. He says it can be attacked and I say it doesn't. Why?. In the event and attacker could fool the user to submit the form with a new password (a classical CSRF attack) he still needs to know the old password, so the attack could never happen.

I presume he's just following the book in the page which reads "all password forms must have CSRF protection". After 2 weeks arguing with them I'll put a CSRF token (after all, I get paid for it) but I still think there is no need (for sure, less than any other input form on the application).

What do you think?. I would like to know if I'm wrong and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning assumes that your users have good password habits. In reality, most users don't. They will have the same password in multiple places, including your website.

This means a CSRF attacker could know their password from an unrelated data breach, or by having a service harvesting passwords for them (i.e. a free image sharing service logging passwords in plaintext, for malicious purposes).

That being said, it is good that you ask, rather than assume you are correct. Security is important, and reasoning as well as asking are good ways to help you learn and develop secure applications.

Comment: This is a good point I didn't thought, and maybe even more in a enterprise environment as is the case, where even some people knows other people's password.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for caring about security in general. I believe here you could find some example of what could go wrong: https://github.com/intelliants/subrion/issues/638

Usually, for critical steps of the user auth, you should apply the zero-trust principle and add as much protection for the customer as possible.

Of course, everything depends on how you designed your application.

Comment: I'm not sure if the link you point me applies exactly to my case. I mean, looks like a typical CSRF attack and I was worried about _my_ case with the old password (which the attacker should previously know). 

Anyway, thank you for the link as I think we should also check for source origin.